# Flatten MonadPlus inside an Aeson Parser

Tags: haskell, composition, aeson, monadplus

I'm not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree here, but I have an Aeson `FromJSON` definition that looks rather bulky and I was wondering if it could be turned into something more concise. I want to short-circuit the parsing of the entire object if the nested parsing of the URI fails.

```
data Link = Link { link :: URI
                 , tags :: [String]
                 } deriving (Show, Typeable, Eq)

instance FromJSON Link where
    parseJSON :: Value -> Parser Link
    parseJSON (Object o) = do
        linkStr <- o .: "link"
        tags' <- o .: "tags"

        case parseURI linkStr of
            Just l -> return $ Link l tags'
            Nothing -> mzero

    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

The type of `parseURI` is `parseURI :: String -> Maybe URI` and both `Maybe` and `Parser` have `MonadPlus` instances. Is there a way to compose the two directly and remove the ugly case statement at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Applicative.html) parsers are usually more concise and you can compose the result of `parseURI` using `maybe mzero return` which converts a `Nothing` into an `mzero`.

```
instance FromJSON Link where
    parseJSON :: Value -> Parser Link
    parseJSON (Object o) = Link
        <$> (maybe mzero return . parseURI =<< o .: "link")
        <*> o .: "tags"

    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Comment: Oh, I was so close in one of my attempts to do this. Thank you, that's exactly the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching works, but this only works inside `do` notation not explicit `>>=` due to the extra desugaring that goes on:

```
instance FromJSON Link where
    parseJSON (Object o) = do
        Just link' <- o .: "link"
        tags'      <- o .: "tags"
        return $ Link link' tags'
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

---

```
> -- Note that I used link :: String for my testing instead
> decode "{\"link\": \"test\", \"tags\": []}" :: Maybe Link
Just (Link {link = "test", tags=[]})
> decode "{\"tags\": []}" :: Maybe Link
Nothing
```

---

What's going on here is that a failed pattern match on the left hand side of a `<-` is calling `fail`.  Looking at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.11.3.4/docs/src/Data-Attoparsec-Internal-Types.html#Parser) for `Parser` tells me that `fail` is calling out to `failDesc`, which is also used by the implementation of `mzero`, so in this case you're safe.  In general it just calls `fail`, which can do any number of things depending on the monad, but for `Parser` I'd say it makes sense.

However, @shang's answer is definitely better since it doesn't rely on implicit behavior.